# How do renewable energy sources deal with reactive loads?

Tags: electrical

If a power grid were to fully switch to renewable power generation methods how would they deal with reactive loads?

Answer (score 2):

They would accomodate them by adding the necessary amount of either capacitance or inductance to the transmission lines to cancel the reactance. Note that this is commonly done today in order to trim the impedance of a large generator to match that of a high-voltage transmission line. It is also done to cancel the reactive component of a large electrical load in a factory that has either a significant amount of inductance or capacitance in it.

Comment: Aren't the billing processes made such as to "encourage" large users to reduce their reactive load - ie the use of Power Factor Control units, so what the generator sees is relatively constant...

Comment: I do not know, but I do know that over here a utility user is billed for resistive +reactive consumption while the only component that performs useful work for him is the resistive component. It is therefore in the utility user's financial interest to trim out the reactive component so he doesn't pay for juice he never got to use.